# Highlight SQL reserved keyword in mvc application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have created script generation application the problem is I'm trying to highlight SQL reserved keywords.

The main problem is `StringBuilder` does not check `ignore-case` if value matches with the same case that time replace value.

SQL reserved keywords:

```
public static string[] SQLRevesedKeyWord = { "int","CREATE","SELECT", "FROM", "WHERE", "NVARCHAR", "INT", "BIGINT", "SMALLINT", "VARCHAR", "CHAR", "BIT", "NTEXT", "DATETIME", "DATE", "TYPE", "AS", "EXEC", "END", "BEGIN", "IF", "ELSE", "ELSE IF", "COMMIT", "TRANSACTION", "TRY", "CATCH", "ROLLBACK", "WITH", "NOLOCK", "TABLE", "INSERT", "INTO", "VALUES", "DELETE" };
```

Replace code:

```
public string ReplaceValue(string s, string Scripts, string ScriptType)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s);
    s = Regex.Replace(s, @"[^a-zA-Z]", " ");

    if (Constants.SQLRevesedKeyWord.Any(s.Contains) || Constants.SQLRevesedKeyWord.Contains(s))
    {
        var querys = s.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        if (querys != null && querys.Length > 0)
        {
            var blueKeywordSql = Constants.SQLRevesedKeyWord.Intersect(querys, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

            foreach (var osqlKeyword in blueKeywordSql)
            {
                sb.Replace(osqlKeyword, string.Concat("<span class=\"sqlBlueKeyword\">", osqlKeyword, "</span>"));
            }
        }
    }

    sb.Replace("'", "''");

    if (Scripts.Equals("Alter"))
    {
        switch (ScriptType)
        {
            case "SP":
                sb.Replace("CREATE PROCEDURE", "<span class=\"sqlBlueKeyword\">ALTER PROCEDURE</span>");
                sb.Replace("CREATE PROC", "<span class=\"sqlBlueKeyword\">ALTER PROC</span>");
                break;

            case "Function":
                sb.Replace("CREATE FUNCTION", "<span class=\"sqlBlueKeyword\">ALTER FUNCTION</span>");
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Output as HTML

```
.jswarp {
    white-space: pre;
    overflow: auto;
}

.sqlBlueKeyword
{
    color: blue;
    font-weight: bold;
}

<div class="col-md-12 jsspdata jswarp"><span class="sqlBlueKeyword"> IF</span> NOT EXISTS( <span class="sqlBlueKeyword">SELECT</span> 1 <span class="sqlBlueKeyword">FROM</span> SYS.OBJECTS <span class="sqlBlueKeyword">WHERE</span> OBJECT_ID = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[spApplyCustomerFilterByDivisionToChildCustomer]') AND <span class="sqlBlueKeyword"> TYPE</span> IN (N'P', N'PC'))
<span class="sqlBlueKeyword">BEGIN</span>
     <span class="sqlBlueKeyword">BEGIN TRANSACTION </span> [spApplyCustomerFilterByDivisionToChildCustomer]
        <span class="sqlBlueKeyword"> BEGIN TRY</span>
         <span class="sqlBlueKeyword">EXEC</span>('      <span class="sqlBlueKeyword">CREATE</span> PROCEDURE [dbo].[spApplyCustomerFilterByDivisionToChildCustomer]
             @CustomerID <span class="sqlBlueKeyword">AS</span> INT
         ,  @CustomerNumber <span class="sqlBlueKeyword">AS</span> <span class="sqlBlueKeyword">NVARCHAR</span>(10)
         ,  @DivisionID INT
         <span class="sqlBlueKeyword">AS</span>

         <span class="sqlBlueKeyword">BEGIN</span>

         -- Temp table for clhild customers having division of same type.
         <span class="sqlBlueKeyword">CREATE</span> <span class="sqlBlueKeyword">TABLE</span> #childCustomers
         (
            CustomerID <span class="sqlBlueKeyword">int</span>,
            CustomerNumber <span class="sqlBlueKeyword">NVARCHAR</span>(10),
            DivisionID <span class="sqlBlueKeyword">int</span>,
            DivisionTypeID <span class="sqlBlueKeyword">int</span>
         )
         -- Temp table for Parent customer filter records
         Create table #ParentDivisionFilter
         (
             CustomerID <span class="sqlBlueKeyword">int</span>,    CustomerNumber <span class="sqlBlueKeyword">NVARCHAR</span>(10),    DivisionID <span class="sqlBlueKeyword">int</span>, DivisionTypeID <span class="sqlBlueKeyword">int</span>,
            ItemID <span class="sqlBlueKeyword">int</span>,ItemCode <span class="sqlBlueKeyword">int</span>,ItemPo<span class="sqlBlueKeyword">int</span> <span class="sqlBlueKeyword">int</span>,ItemMaxQuantity <span class="sqlBlueKeyword">int</span>
         )

         -- customer filter records
         Insert into #ParentDivisionFilter
         select cf.CustomerID,cf.CustomerNumber,cf.CustomerDivisionID, cdt.[ID] as DivisionTypeID,
         cf.ItemID,cf.ItemCode,cf.ItemPoint ,cf.ItemMaxQuantity
         from CustomerFilter cf
         join CustomerDivision cd on cd.ID=cf.CustomerDivisionID
         join CustomerDivisionType cdt on cdt.ID= cd.DivisionTypeID
         where cf.CustomerID=@CustomerID and cf.CustomerDivisionID=@DivisionID

         -- Geting child customers
         ;<span class="sqlBlueKeyword">WITH</span> childs <span class="sqlBlueKeyword">AS</span>(
                 <span class="sqlBlueKeyword">SELECT</span>  *
                 <span class="sqlBlueKeyword">FROM</span>    Customer
                 <span class="sqlBlueKeyword">WHERE</span>   ID = @CustomerID
                 UNION ALL
                 <span class="sqlBlueKeyword">SELECT</span>  t.*
                 <span class="sqlBlueKeyword">FROM</span>    Customer t INNER JOIN
                         childs r ON t.CustomerGroupID = r.ID
         )
         insert Into #childCustomers
         <span class="sqlBlueKeyword">SELECT</span>  childs.ID,childs.CustomerNumber,cd.ID as DivisionID,cdt.[ID] <span class="sqlBlueKeyword">AS</span> DivisionTypeID
         <span class="sqlBlueKeyword">FROM</span>    childs
         join CustomerDivision cd on cd.CustomerID=childs.ID
         join CustomerDivisionType cdt on cdt.ID= cd.DivisionTypeID
         join #ParentDivisionFilter flt on flt.DivisionTypeID=cdt.ID
         where childs.ID!=@CustomerID

         Declare @ChildCustomerID <span class="sqlBlueKeyword">AS</span> INT;
         Declare    @ChildCustomerNumber <span class="sqlBlueKeyword">AS</span> <span class="sqlBlueKeyword">NVARCHAR</span>(10);
         Declare    @ChildDivisionID INT;

         Declare applyFilter CURSOR FOR
         Select CustomerID,CustomerNumber,DivisionID From #childCustomers

         Open applyFilter
         Fetch Next from applyFilter <span class="sqlBlueKeyword">INTO</span> @ChildCustomerID,@ChildCustomerNumber,@ChildDivisionID

         While @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
         <span class="sqlBlueKeyword">BEGIN</span>

         Delete from CustomerFilter where  CustomerID=@ChildCustomerID and CustomerDivisionID=@ChildDivisionID AND CustomerNumber=@ChildCustomerNumber

         <span class="sqlBlueKeyword">INSERT</span> Into CustomerFilter(
                CustomerID,CustomerNumber,CustomerDivisionID,ItemID,ItemCode,ItemPoint,ItemMaxQuantity,Creator,DateCreated,Modifier,DateModified)
                Select @ChildCustomerID,@ChildCustomerNumber,@ChildDivisionID,ItemID,ItemCode,ItemPoint,ItemMaxQuantity,''admin'',GETDATE(),''admin'',GETDATE()
                from #ParentDivisionFilter

                Fetch Next from applyFilter <span class="sqlBlueKeyword">INTO</span> @ChildCustomerID,@ChildCustomerNumber,@ChildDivisionID
         <span class="sqlBlueKeyword">END</span>

         close applyFilter
         deallocate applyFilter

         Select * from #childCustomers

         <span class="sqlBlueKeyword">END</span>

         ')
             <span class="sqlBlueKeyword"> COMMIT TRANSACTION </span> [spApplyCustomerFilterByDivisionToChildCustomer]
        <span class="sqlBlueKeyword"> END TRY </span>
        <span class="sqlBlueKeyword"> BEGIN CATCH</span>
             SELECT ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage
             <span class="sqlBlueKeyword">ROLLBACK TRANSACTION</span> [spApplyCustomerFilterByDivisionToChildCustomer]
         <span class="sqlBlueKeyword">END CATCH </span>
<span class="sqlBlueKeyword">END</span></div>
```

Here you can see int not highlighted because case, not match.

Any can help me solved the above issues.